# Module to rotate the content continously

Tags: 7

Any one knows how to rotate the content of particular content type continuously from down to upward direction without pausing.

The contents should rotate continuously together. I have used `viewTicker` and `view slideshow` and `content glider` modules.

Please tell me other module.

Answer (score 0):

Jcarousel might help you for creating slide shows. It works even with views so you can create a views slideshow with it. It also have an automatic slide rotation which I think you were after. https://drupal.org/project/jcarousel

Comment: no I did not find the solution by jcarousel module

Comment: becauze this module allows the rotation by clicking at the arrow. But i want continuos rotation.

Comment: It has the continuous rotation so you do not need to click on arrows. But I do not remember where it was. Just search for it.